# Simplify expressions that contain full derivatives

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The best way to show what I want is by giving an example:

How to go from

```
Exp[-a[x, y]] (g[x, y]*Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y])/h[x, y] + 
Exp[-a[x, y]] (f[x, y]*Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y])/h[x, y] - 
Exp[-a[x, y]] (f[x, y]*g[x, y]*Derivative[1, 0][h][x, y])/h[x, y]^2
```

to

```
Exp[-a[x, y]] D[f[x, y]*g[x, y]/h[x, y], x]
```

If the Exp were not there, i.e. the expression is a full derivative, then integrating would work [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22014/how-to-simplify-expressions-containing-derivatives)

```
expr = With[{anti = 
Integrate[(g[x, y]*Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y])/
h[x, y] + (f[x, y]*Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y])/
h[x, y] - (f[x, y]*g[x, y]*Derivative[1, 0][h][x, y])/h[x, y]^2,
x]}, HoldForm[D[anti, x]]]
```

Comment: `DSolve[Exp[-a[x, y]] (g[x, y]*Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y])/h[x, y] + 
   Exp[-a[x, y]] (f[x, y]*Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y])/h[x, y] - 
   Exp[-a[x, y]] (f[x, y]*g[x, y]*Derivative[1, 0][h][x, y])/
     h[x, y]^2 == Exp[-a[x, y]] Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y], z, {x, y}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Extending my comment to [@MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22017/109)'s answer, you could consider

```
 simp[exp_] := Simplify[exp, 
    TransformationFunctions -> {
(Block[{x}, Defer[D[#, x]] &[Integrate[#, x]]] &), Collect[#, _^_] &}]
```