# How to work out sums symbolically?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, summation, algebraic-manipulation

**Intro**

Consider these two equal expressions of the variance

$$\frac{\sum _{i=1}^n x(i)^2}{n}-\frac{\left(\sum _{i=1}^n x(i)\right){}^2}{n^2}$$

and

$$\frac{\sum _{i=1}^n \left(x(i)-\frac{\sum _{i=1}^n x(i)}{n}\right){}^2}{n}$$

I tried to run `Simplify` on them but they did not boil down to the same expression. I also tried to test if they are equal with:

```
Reduce[Sum[x[i]^2/n, {i, 1, n}] - Sum[x[i]/n, {i, 1, n}]^2 == 
  Sum[(x[i] - Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]/n)^2/n, {i, 1, n}]]
```

but it fails to return either `True` or `False`. I think the issue is that it cannot treat expressions like `x[i]` symbolically but needs an actual array.

**General Question**

How to work out sums (and other iterative operations on array such as products) symbolically?

**Specific question**

My personal goal is to see if there is a way to simplify this expression further than what I managed to do by hand

$$\frac{\frac{d-1}{d} s^2}{\bar X - \bar X^2 + \frac{s^2}{r} \left(1-\frac{r-1}{d-1}\right)}$$

, where $\bar X = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^r X_i}{r}$ and $s^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^r X_i - \bar X}{r-1}$

In Mathematica terms it gives

```
(((d - 1)/(d*(r - 1)))*
   Sum[(x[i] - Sum[x[i], {i, 1, r}]/r)^2, {i, 1, 
     r}])/(Sum[(x[i]/r)*(1 - Sum[x[i]/r, {i, 1, r}]), {i, 1, r}] + 
      Sum[((x[i] - Sum[x[i], {i, 1, r}]/r)^2/(d*(d - 1)))*(1 - (r - 
          1)/(d - 1)), {i, 1, r}])
```

Comment: To share complex expressions, take a look at: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65471) might be and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21007) of interest.

Comment: I think the problem here is that providing a general solution (that you seek) will not yield a nice answer to your specific question. Zugzwang.