# Analytically express chi-square sum and solve

Tags: replacement, summation, rule

I have an expression:

```
chisq[f_, x_, y_, e_, pars__] := Sum[((y[k] - f@@Join[{x[k]},pars])/e[k])^2, {k,1,n}]
```

which should work for any function that has `x` as an argument, as well as some arbitrary number of parameters. Say, if I have `a` and `b`, `chisq[f,x,y,e,{a,b}]` will give

[image]

which is just an expression of chi-square $\chi^2$ for a set of data $\{x_i, y_i\pm e_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ against a model described by `f[x,a,b]`.

What I want to do is calculate $\nabla\chi^2 $ to solve $\nabla \chi^2=0$ . If I take derivative against `a`, `D[chisq[f,x,y,e,{a,b}],a]`, the result is

[image]

which is not technically wrong. But I want to arrange this into a format so that it could be solved, by extracting the multiplicative constants out of the summation and splitting the summation into pieces. For example, `Simplify[D[chisq[f,x,y,e,{a,b}],a]/2]` gives

[image]

which has 2 in all of its terms but does not get it out of the sum. What I want it to happen is something like
$$
\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\left(y_i - f(x_i;a,b)\right)^2}{{e_i}^2}
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\chi^2 = 2 \left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{f(x_i;a,b) \partial_a f(x_i;a,b) - y_i \partial_a f(x_i;a,b)}{{e_i}^2}\right]
\\
= 2 \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{f(x_i;a,b) \partial_a f(x_i;a,b)}{{e_i}^2} - 2 \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{y_i \partial_a f(x_i;a,b)}{{e_i}^2}
$$

For example, it should work for linear fit $f(x;a,b) = a+bx$,

$$
\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\left(y_i - a - b x_i\right)^2}{{e_i}^2}
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\chi^2
= 2 \left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{a+b x_i}{{e_i}^2} -  \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{y_i}{{e_i}^2}\right]
= 2 \left[a \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{{e_i}^2} + b \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{x_i}{{e_i}^2} -  \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{y_i}{{e_i}^2}\right]
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\chi^2
= 2 \left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\left(a+b x_i\right) x_i}{{e_i}^2} -  \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{y_i x_i}{{e_i}^2}\right]
= 2 \left[a \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{ x_i}{{e_i}^2} + b \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{{x_i}^2}{{e_i}^2} -  \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{y_i x_i}{{e_i}^2}\right]
$$

and so on. How can I make the sum `D[chisq[f,x,y,e,{a,b}],a]` to be expanded like this?

---

Edit: **I've narrowed down the problem, but not out of the woods yet.**

I think I'm halfway there. Thanks to a post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199464/29247 and with a lot of experimentation, I somehow got hold of some set of rules, which could do what I want when successively applied several times.

First, the one from aforementioned post

```
Sum[Times[Longest[u___], x_] , {y_, z___}] :> 
    Times[u] Sum[Times[x], {y, z}] /;(FreeQ[{u}, y])
```

can extract multiplicative factor.

Second,

```
Sum[Plus[ Longest[u___], x_] , {y_, z___}] :> Plus[Sum[u, {y, z}], Sum[x, {y, z}]]
```

will split the summation.

Third,

```
Times[Plus[Longest[u___], v_],x_] :> Times[Plus[u], x] + Times[v, x]
```

is used for expanding the fraction, since when it's multiplied with common factor, it is not recognized by two rules above.

So, for instance,

```
Sum[(a[k] + q b[k])/(c[k]), {k,1,n}] /.
    Times[Plus[Longest[u___], v_],x_] :> Times[Plus[u], x] + Times[v, x] /.
    Sum[Plus[ Longest[u___], x_] , {y_, z___}] :> Plus[Sum[u, {y, z}], Sum[x, {y, z}]] /.
    Sum[Times[Longest[u___], x_] , {y_, z___}] :> Times[u] Sum[Times[x], {y, z}] /;(FreeQ[{u}, y])
```

I get what I want:

[image]

But if I make it a set of rules then apply,

```
Sum[(a[k] + q b[k])/(c[k]), {k,1,n}] //. {
    Times[Plus[Longest[u___], v_],x_] :> Times[Plus[u], x] + Times[v, x] ,
    Sum[Plus[ Longest[u___], x_] , {y_, z___}] :> Plus[Sum[u, {y, z}], Sum[x, {y, z}]] ,
    Sum[Times[Longest[u___], x_] , {y_, z___}] :> Times[u] Sum[Times[x], {y, z}] /;(FreeQ[{u}, y])
}
```

I get

[image]

I figured that it seems the rule from the aforementioned post

```
Sum[Times[Longest[u___], x_] , {y_, z___}] :> 
    Times[u] Sum[Times[x], {y, z}] /;(FreeQ[{u}, y])
```

is causing this problem. If I remove it from the rules and apply separately, it seems to work as intended. But I don't understand this behavior. I mean, I'm novice in terms of Wolfram Language, and I understand almost none of what is happening. So, could someone explain why this isn't working, and what I should do to make it work as a single list of rules?

Comment: Let us put `f[x_, a_, b_] := a*x + b;`, then `D[chisq[f, x, y, e, {a, b}], a]` results in $$\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2 a x(k)^2+2 b x(k)-2 x(k) y(k)}{e(k)^2} .$$ Why do you dislike it? As far as I remember it, there are some tricks to extract `2` outside the sum.

Comment: @user64494 1. The "trick to extract 2 outside the sum" is one of what I'm asking here. 2. I need to split the sums into smaller sub-sums so that I could manipulate to get answer. 3. I need to extract not only 2 but `a` and `b` as well, since they don't explicitly depend on the iterative index of the sum.

Comment: Ideally, What I want to do is `Solve[D[chisq[f, x, y, e, {a, b}, a]==0, a]` or `Solve[{D[chisq[f, x, y, e, {a, b}, a]==0, D[chisq[f, x, y, e, {a, b}, b]==0}, {a,b}]`.